# Why can't I access the second element of this void type array

Tags: c, arrays, function-pointers, void-pointers

I am trying to sort an array of type void, just to brush up on my void pointers and function pointers, its been a while.

Here is my main c file:

```
    #include "hawksort.h"
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define ARR_LEN 10

    int compareNumbers(void*,void*);

    int main (int argc, char** argv)
    {
       int i =0;
       int* arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*ARR_LEN);
       for(i = 0; i < ARR_LEN; i++){
           arr[i] = ARR_LEN - i;
           printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
       }
       printf("here\n");
       hawkBubbleSort(&compareNumbers, (void*)&arr, ARR_LEN);
       return 0;
    }

    int compareNumbers(void* a, void* b)
    {
       printf("%d\n", *(int*)a);
       printf("%d\n", *(int*)b);

       if(*(int*)a > *(int*)b)
           return 1;
       if(*(int*)a < *(int*)b)
           return -1;
       if(*(int*)a == *(int*)b)
           return 0;
       return 0;
}
```

and here is my header file containing the sorting

```
    int hawkBubbleSort(int (*comparisonAlgo)(void*,void*), void** a, int size){
       int i = 0;

       printf("%d\n",*(int*)a[0]);
       printf("%d\n",*(int*)a[1]);

       int swapped = 1;
       while(swapped == 1){
           swapped = 0;
           for(i = 1; i < size; i++){
               if(comparisonAlgo(a[i-1],a[i]) >= 1){
                   printf("Bigger\n");
                   void* temp = a[i];
                   a[i] = a[i-1];
                   a[i-1] = temp;
                   swapped = 1;
               }
           }
       }

       return 1;
   }
```

The problem is, I am getting a segmentation fault when I try to access a[1].  a[0] returns the correct number of 10.  I don't know where the issue is.  I have a feeling its a problem with the type sizes and incrementing through the array, although it is possible I just messed up passing arr into the hawkBubbleSort function.

Sample output:
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
here
10
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: You have code in your header? Why?

Comment: I see no reason whatsoever why `arr` is being passed to this by address. Its value already *is* the address of your array sequence.

Comment: @WhozCraig What would I pass it in by instead? (void**)arr or just (void*)arr?

Comment: If your intent is to mimic how the standard library `qsort` implements sequence passing, you pass (a) the base address of the sequence, (b) the stride of the element type in the sequence (in this case `sizeof(int)`, and the number of elements. Armed with those three values sequence sorting is possible. Without all three you are confined to assuming one (in your case, your assuming `int`).

Comment: also, you pass the pointer of type void* to pointer of type void** and you'll get segmentation fault when callign a[1]  on the beginning of hawkBubbleSort...

Comment: @WhozCraig Ah, that makes sense. Then I'll just increment the pointer by the size of my data type to access individual elements. I see. Thank you!

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks Careful, incrementing a `void*` is non-standard. Upon entry into your function if you're adjusting by-element-stride, you need a octet-pointer (ex: `unsigned char *`).

Comment: you have completely messed the pointer logic. You have to sort either the data or the pointers, but you have data and you are trying to sort pointers made of the data...

Comment: @WhozCraig This implementation sounds horrendously useless then and I will likely a different set of practice problems

Comment: That's right @Hawkeye. Avoid void. Why are you declaring `void` arguments for `hawkBubbleSort()` when quite clearly it knows their type? by comparison, `qsort()` takes a void pointer and the data width and the array size. The reason function arguments and return values are declared as void, is when they are general purpose and don't need a type. For example `malloc()` returns a void pointer because it does not know what you want it for.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks! Yeah, I was basically making my own qsort() i guess, but I didn't have all the arguments I needed, so it was borderline impossible

Comment: this line: hawkBubbleSort(&compareNumbers, (void*)&arr, ARR_LEN); needs some modification, because arr is already a pointer and you do not want to change that pointer, just the items it is pointing to, so the line should be: hawkBubbleSort(&compareNumbers, (void*)arr, ARR_LEN);

Comment: then, this line: int hawkBubbleSort(int (*comparisonAlgo)(void*,void*), void** a, int size){ should be: int hawkBubbleSort(int (*comparisonAlgo)(void*,void*), void* a, int size){  However, since all items are expecting the array to be an array of int values, it would be much better to write all items as int* rather than void*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pointer usage is incorrect. You cannot simply pass a `void**` and peel it apart expecting it works as a universal sequence addressing mechanism.

To build an universal sorting routine taking an arbitrary sequence and a comparison function is considerably more tedious than a straight-forward type-based sort routine. For your sort function, the following should be provided.

- The base address of the sequence being sorted.
- The width (or stride) of any single sequence element.
- The number of elements being sorted.
- The comparison function.

The library function [**`qsort()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort), not coincidentally, takes these very parameters to accomplish its task, and likewise so should you. Another utility that comes in handy is a function that swaps memory from two non-overlapping regions Armed with all the above, your task becomes simply the following. I *strongly* advise you review it compared to your code, in particular how the pointers passed to the comparator are adjusted based on element stride. As a bonus, I optimized the bubble-sort algorithm (an oxymoron if ever there was one):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARR_LEN 10

void memswp(void *a, void *b, size_t len)
{
    unsigned char *lhs = a, *rhs = b;
    size_t i=0;
    for (i=0;i<len;++i)
    {
        unsigned char tmp = lhs[i];
        lhs[i] = rhs[i];
        rhs[i] = tmp;
    }
}


int hawkBubbleSort(void* a, size_t len, size_t elemsiz, int (*cmp)(const void*,const void*))
{
    unsigned char *p = a;
    size_t i=0;

    int swapped = 1;
    while(swapped && len-- > 0)
    {
        swapped = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            if(cmp(p+(i*elemsiz), p+((i+1)*elemsiz)) > 0)
            {
                memswp(p+(i*elemsiz), p+((i+1)*elemsiz), elemsiz);
                swapped = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int compareNumbers(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    int const *lhs = a, *rhs = b;
    int res = (*lhs < *rhs) ? -1 : (*rhs < *lhs);
    printf("cmp(%d,%d) ==> %d\n", *lhs, *rhs, res);
    return res;
}


int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    int *arr = malloc(ARR_LEN * sizeof(*arr)), i;

    for(i = 0; i < ARR_LEN; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = ARR_LEN - i;
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    hawkBubbleSort(arr, ARR_LEN, sizeof(*arr), &compareNumbers);

    for(i = 0; i < ARR_LEN; i++)
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    hawkBubbleSort(arr, ARR_LEN, sizeof(*arr), &compareNumbers);

    for(i = 0; i < ARR_LEN; i++)
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
cmp(10,9) ==> 1
cmp(10,8) ==> 1
cmp(10,7) ==> 1
cmp(10,6) ==> 1
cmp(10,5) ==> 1
cmp(10,4) ==> 1
cmp(10,3) ==> 1
cmp(10,2) ==> 1
cmp(10,1) ==> 1
cmp(9,8) ==> 1
cmp(9,7) ==> 1
cmp(9,6) ==> 1
cmp(9,5) ==> 1
cmp(9,4) ==> 1
cmp(9,3) ==> 1
cmp(9,2) ==> 1
cmp(9,1) ==> 1
cmp(8,7) ==> 1
cmp(8,6) ==> 1
cmp(8,5) ==> 1
cmp(8,4) ==> 1
cmp(8,3) ==> 1
cmp(8,2) ==> 1
cmp(8,1) ==> 1
cmp(7,6) ==> 1
cmp(7,5) ==> 1
cmp(7,4) ==> 1
cmp(7,3) ==> 1
cmp(7,2) ==> 1
cmp(7,1) ==> 1
cmp(6,5) ==> 1
cmp(6,4) ==> 1
cmp(6,3) ==> 1
cmp(6,2) ==> 1
cmp(6,1) ==> 1
cmp(5,4) ==> 1
cmp(5,3) ==> 1
cmp(5,2) ==> 1
cmp(5,1) ==> 1
cmp(4,3) ==> 1
cmp(4,2) ==> 1
cmp(4,1) ==> 1
cmp(3,2) ==> 1
cmp(3,1) ==> 1
cmp(2,1) ==> 1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
cmp(1,2) ==> -1
cmp(2,3) ==> -1
cmp(3,4) ==> -1
cmp(4,5) ==> -1
cmp(5,6) ==> -1
cmp(6,7) ==> -1
cmp(7,8) ==> -1
cmp(8,9) ==> -1
cmp(9,10) ==> -1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Best of luck.

Comment: this line: int *arr = malloc(ARR_LEN * sizeof(*arr)) will give a malloc for an array of pointers to integer, not an array of integers.  This may work if pointers and integers are the same size, however; I would not place any bets on that being true.

Comment: the OPs code assumes the array is an array of integers, as does most of the rest of the code (except that business of casting many of the pointers as void*.)  Therefore, since the OP did not say they were trying to produce a 'generic' bubble sort algorithm, the whole code set should be working with an array of int.

Comment: @user3629249 you're **wrong**. `sizeof(*arr)` is equivalent to `sizeof(int)`.  Therefore, `int *arr = malloc(ARR_LEN * sizeof(*arr));` allocates the correct amount of memory.  Were I to have used `sizeof(arr)` you statement would be correct, but as written your flat-wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed several severe mistakes in you code:

1. the way you pass `compareNumbers`. a function pointer of a function should be the name itself. you if you pass `&compareNumbers`, you are passing `int (**)(void*,void*)`, which i don't think you want it.
2. the implmentation of `compareNumbers` show me that you still want to sort `int` in this case, but you want to make you sorting function generic. however, your sorting function has no reflection of that. so to fix it, you should have your sorting function takes another parameter, which should be the element size of the array. so the result prototype of the function should be:

   int hawkBubbleSort(int (*comparisonAlgo)(void*,void*), void* arr[], int length, size_t elem_size);
3. the way you pass in the array. your casting is wrong. it should be `(void **)arr`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very important rule to follow when working with void pointers: *never dereference them*.

The reason for this is that whenever you do pointer arithmetic in C, what happens behind the scene is that the compiler, knowing the size of the type you're working on, will replace an access like this:

```
int* anArray = calloc(5, sizeof(int));
int i = anArray[2]; // which, is the same as *(anArray + 2);
```

with the actual proper offset needed to get to that variable:

```
int i = anArray + 2*sizeof(int);
```

But if we're working with void*, the compiler cannot know the size of the type stored in the array! It will therefore move by 1 byte, the smallest memory increment.

The solution is to always cast void* to a variable with the correct type before dereferencing it.

In your case:

```
int hawkBubbleSort(int (*comparisonAlgo)(void*,void*), void** a, int size){
   int i = 0;
   int** array = (int**)a;

   printf("%d\n",*(int*)array[0]);
   printf("%d\n",*(int*)array[1]);

   int swapped = 1;
   while(swapped == 1){
       swapped = 0;
       for(i = 1; i < size; i++){
           if(comparisonAlgo(array[i-1],array[i]) >= 1){
               printf("Bigger\n");
               int* temp = array[i];
               array[i] = array[i-1];
               array[i-1] = temp;
               swapped = 1;
           }
       }
   }
```

Edited with original snippet.

Comment: There are several definitions of `a` in the OP's source, and as you do not quote any of tehm your snippets are ambiguous.

Comment: Assuming `void** a;`: This `int i = a + 1*sizeof(a);` does not look like valid C. And here `printf("%d\n", *a[1]); ` I suspect a typo and some missing parentheses.

Comment: Edited for clarity. I meant to show the mechanics of a generic array access.

Comment: The intention of hawkBubbleSort() was to be type independent, at least in terms of what's in the function. By that I mean, no assuming it is int or not. Therefore the int** array wouldn't be proper.  Any type assumptions would be done in the comparisonAlgo() function.  That said, I appreciate the help and I'm sure this logic can be applied elsewhere

Comment: 1st: This `anArray + 2*sizeof(int);` doesn't return an `int` but a`int*`. 2nd: the `int*` returned by the former points to `anArray[8-1]` ( assuming `sizeof (int)` to be equal 4).

Comment: Also: `It will therefore move by 1 byte` is not Standard C. Standard C does not define arithmetics on `void`-pointers. It might however be implemented as an extension, as gcc does for example.

Comment: Also^2: This `*(int*)array[1]` does not access the second element in `arr`, but provokes undefined behaviour. To access `arr[1]` do `((int*)(*array))[1]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the address to this int array pointer, which would be `(void**) &arr`.

This will pass the array by reference, and it has to be a double pointer because an array in C is already a pointer.